# unexpected output in docker container

Tags: shell, docker, export

I have below script to get values from config:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -u10 line
do
if echo $line | grep -v -e "^#" -e "^$" | grep -F "=" &>/dev/null
then
varname=$(echo "$line" | cut -f1 -d '=')
export $varname=$(echo "$line" | cut -f2 -d '=')
fi
done 10< ./config
echo $a
```

My config like below:

```
a="b"
```

when at my host, it print `a` as `b`, but in container, it print `a` as `"b"`.

Could anyone know why?

Comment: What's the version of bash inside and outside the container?

Comment: It is the same `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`